# Calculating the number of needed error correction words in QR code

Tags: qr-code, iso, error-correction, reed-solomon

I like to encode QR codes. Therefore I need to know, how much error correction words are needed by an specified version and correction level. 
For QR version 1 in combination with ec-level Q there must be 13 error correction words and 13 data words.
I know there are some tables (table 7,8,9) in the ISO/IEC 18004 where this information is stored. But I like to know if it's possible to calculate the amount of needed error correction words.

Greets,
Raffi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need ISO 18004. I suppose you could also look at [the source code from zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/Encoder.java) that calculates this. It happens around the method `interleaveWithECBytes`.